# Matlab Crahes upon fopen in Mex File

Tags: c, matlab, fopen, mex

I have a little experience with Matlab, but am new to the mex environment.

What I am trying to do is to save some values I compute to a txt file in my C routine.

For the sake of simplicity I am using the example arrayProduct.c from MathWork's [Create C Source File guide](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/standalone-example.html) here to elaborate.

I modified the example code in the following way:

```
void arrayProduct(double x, double *y, double *z, mwSize n)
{
  mwSize i;

  /* multiply each element y by x */
  FILE *f = NULL;
  f = fopen("log_test.csv", "rb");
  for (i=0; i<n; i++) 
  {
    z[i] = x * y[i];
    fprintf(f, "%g\n", z[i]);
  }
  fclose(f);
}
```

So I added the declaration of *f*, the *fopen*, the *fprintf* and the *fclose* commands.
I am using **MS Visual Studio C++ 2013 Professional (C)** as a compiler and the code compiles just fine.
Through uncommenting all my changes and introducing them bit by bit again I was able to find out that Matlab crashes at the *fopen* command.

I wasn't able to find useful help here or elsewhere, so any suggestions are very welcome. Thanks very much in advance!

Kind Regards

Philipp

Comment: Whit crashes, do you mean it got stuck?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `w+` instead of `rw`? Or `r+`.... Does the file `log_test.csv` already exist?

Comment: Hey, no, it closes down entirely. It is Matlab 2015a on Win7 64bit

Comment: Why don't you have any error checking on your call to `fopen()` ?

Comment: @RobertStettler, thank you very much, that already seems to be it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `w+` or `r+` when using `fopen`, depending on what you want to do with the file and whethe you want to create it or simply open it.

From (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm)

- "r"  Opens a file for reading. The file must exist.
- "w"  Creates an empty file for writing. If a file with the same name already exists, its content is erased and the file is considered as a new empty file.
- "a"  Appends to a file. Writing operations, append data at the end of the file. The file is created if it does not exist.
- "r+"     Opens a file to update both reading and writing. The file must exist.
- "w+"     Creates an empty file for both reading and writing.
- "a+"     Opens a file for reading and appending.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the helpful comments, especially by RobertStettler!
The problem was with the mode I opened the file with. it should rather be r+, w+ or a+.

Comment: You're welcome, I posted the answer in littlebit more detail so you can close the topic.